# SQLAlchemy - Inhertiance write attribute entry into two tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Maybe an easy one for others.
I want to write the name of a child object into the parent table AND into the child table:

```
class Object(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'object'

    id     = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name   = Column(db.String(50))

class ChildObject(Objekt):
    __tablename__ = 'child_object'

    id     = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('object.id'), primary_key=True)
    name    = Object.name

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'ChildObject'
    }
```

How can I do this?